# How to save form data if internet connection is down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, local-storage

I developed Single Page Application that will be by our customers to enter data in various forms. Some of them will go out on the filed and gather information from clients. In these situation they might use `hotspot` and their connection might go up and down depends on reception. In the app they can enter one client data/form at the time. So they were wondering if connection goes down what will happen with the data that is already entered. Since this app is using AJAX they should have the problem until they hit `submit` button. Once that process is triggered and connection is down they won't be able to save the data. So my question is what would be the best practice in this situation? I explored some option and one of them would be to store data in `local storage` that is supported in HTML5. Here is example of my code:

```
$('#'+frmID).on('submit', function(e){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            encoding:"UTF-8",
            url: 'Application.cfc?method='+frmID,
            data: formData,
            dataType: 'json'
        }).done(function(obj){
            if(obj.STATUS === 200){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            if(jqXHR.status == 0){
                //Here I would notify user if connection is down and save the data in temporary storage
            }else{
                alert("Error: "+errorThrown);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I'm wondering since User will be saving the data for one client at the time should I create local storage `key` for each client and use that as unique key or there is a better way to do this? Also how I should handle the situation if they access same client later once connection is back? Should I give them an option to load the old data once they open the form? If anyone can provide some example or advise what is the best approach please let me know. I'm looking for long term solution that should be reliable since this data can be large and sensitive as well. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You appear to have considered many of the available options. What is the issue implementing the procedure?

Comment: There is no issue implementing it. I never before used local storage and I'm wondering if that would be a good fit for this particular case.

Comment: You can try and determine the answer yourself.

Comment: @guest271314 Great help. Thanks!

Comment: I've used local storage libs for this problem a view times. Can recommend this approach.

Comment: I would recommend creating just one localstorage keys and storing the data as json.

Comment: @JesseSchokker So you are suggesting to create one key for example fomrData and then dump all form data in that local storage?

Comment: Yeah. Will be more easy to keep track of the data then. JSON data is really easy to handle with JavaScript. Just call JSON.parse(jsondata); to transform the JSON to a JavaScript object.